# div fill the remaining space screen

Tags: css, html

I want to ask can I make a `div` to fill the entire remaining space.

I need to make site with 2 parts - one always on top and one always on bottom

You can give me some ideas for this (without position:absolute;)

So here is my idea - 3 Divs with classes:
HTML:

```
<div class="top"><div>
<div class="center" ></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Css:

```
.bottom{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}
.top{
display:block;
min-height: 250px;
}
.center{
display:block;
min-height:30px;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Your objective is not clear.  Are `.top` and `.bottom` going to be fixed heights?  Is it important for `.center` to always fill the space, or are you just wanting this area to have a certain background color.  You should put more effort and detail in your question so people can actually help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "remaining space"?  Do you mean the remaining space on the screen?  The remaining space on the parent?  Could you create a JSFiddle for an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Axel Yes, they are with fixed height, but I don't know on what screen resolution the site will be ran because it's mobile version.

Comment: Are `.top` and `.bottom` fixed (meaning they will always appear, or will they scroll off screen when the `.center` has enough content to fill the screen vertically?

Comment: @Alex I think the browser makes them fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the divs an ID You can use jQuery like so:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeWindow();
});

function resizeWindow() {
    var sHeight = $(window).height();
    var tHeight = $("#top").height();
    var bHeight = $("#bottom").height();
    var nHeight = sHeight - tHeight - bHeight;
    $("#center").height(nHeight);
}
```

The resize part also allows for anyone resizing the screen and if someone with a tablet/smartphone changes the orientation.

Comment: Thanks but i got little problem with jQuery (i'm still learning) here is my code.I have changed them to id in the html/css and this is my code for jquery http://pastebin.com/Hj3zx2nW and it don't work

Comment: can you provide new html as well?  Can you also try calling resizeWindow() in document.ready function?

Comment: Can you check the function is hit by putting an alert() or something in there.  If it is hit, can you use something like Chrome and inspect the divs to ensure they are given a height.  Also change the css so that #center has a height:100% and remove the other two options.

Comment: Can you put what it was for other ppl to see

Comment: It was my mistake. They must run once the function in document ready and place the code outside of document ready.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want three div's stacked on top of eachother.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="top"><div>
    <div class="center" ></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div> 
</div> 

#container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
    .bottom{
    position:relative;
    height:25%;
    width:100%;
    }
    .top{
    position:relative;
    height:25%;
    width:100%;
    }
    .center{
    position:relative;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't told i want them 25%-50%-25%.